# error using vector::begin() :no suitable conversion function from ... " to "int" exists

Tags: c++, error-handling, iterator

I am trying to sort a vector of integers using selection method.

I am using `vector::begin()` to iterate over the elements of the vector, however, something is wrong in the iteration that make such an error as below:

What is the problem here?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

void selection_sort(std::vector<int> vec);

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec = {2 , 8 , 5 , 3 , 9 , 4 , 1};
    selection_sort(vec);
}

void selection_sort(std::vector<int> vec){

    for(int j = vec.begin() ; j < vec.size() ; j++){ //searching from the first vec index to the last index of vec

        int min = j; //current min always is assigned to the first unsorted element

        for (int i = vec.begin() + j ; i < vec.size() ; i++){ //starting searching in the ubsorted numbers

            if (vec[i] < vec[min]){ //if one of unsorted elements is smaller than the first unsorted element, that will be the min

                min = i;  //min between unsorted numbers
            }
            std::swap(vec[min] , vec[j]); //swaping th efinal min of unsorted elements with the firstr unsorted element
        }
    } 
    for (int i = vec.begin() ; i < vec.size() ; i++){
        std::cout<<vec[i];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin - Your book should cover iterators.

Comment: You probably meant `int j = 0;` and `int i = 0;`. `begin` is to get an iterator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes it solved the problem. My confusion is between index and iterator when addressing elements of a vector!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the loops should be using `vector::size_type` or even `std::size_t` instead of `int`. `vector::size()` does not return an `int` and `vector::operator[]` does not take `int` indexes.